# How do I keep the result of a pointerover event for debugging with DevTool?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have an element that would listen to `pointerover` event. When it is hovered by pointer like mouse, it will show a tooltip.

I am trying to debug this, but when move my mouse away from that element and tried to click the DOM tree in DevTool, the `pointerout` event would fire and clean up the result, which makes debugging extremely hard. Is it possible to keep the state of a specific event, when I use the DevTool?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Emulate a focused page" option in DevTools. Here is how

1. Focus on the element
2. In DevTools, open the `Rendering` tab via 3-dot > More options > Rendering, then check and uncheck "Emulate a focused page".

We explain that in official video and docs:

- video: https://youtu.be/2baY3JpCxpo?t=158
- link: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/rendering/apply-effects/#emulate-a-focused-page